# How do I integrate this function in python?

Tags: python, interpolation, quadrature

Essentially this is the problem:

$\hat{F}(\omega) = \int_0^{\infty} f(s)e^{-i\omega s}ds$

The function $f$ is in general complex valued. I know this looks like the fourier transform but I don't want to view it that way. So in my implementation $f(s)$ and $\omega$ are going to be numpy vectors representing the sampled values of the true function or range. For my purposes I want to evaluate the integral for

```
omega = np.linspace(-30,30,0.1)
```

i.e. $-30\le\omega \le30$ with spacing of $0.1$

Can someone suggest a python implementation for this? I have done some quick research and some sources suggest using 'Gauss Laguerre' integration routine. I'm not sure why, but if someone could motivate this I would be grateful.

Comment: Because Gauss-Laguerre quadrature is designed explicitly to deal with integrals from $0$ to $\infty$ with inverse exponential weights, see  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Laguerre_quadrature. The nodes and weights can be computed using NumPy via `numpy.polynomial.laguerre.laggauss()` (see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.laguerre.laggauss.html#numpy.polynomial.laguerre.laggauss), so the implementation should be straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you don't want to interpret the results as a Fourier transform, can't you make use of the builtin FT routines in numpy as an efficient way to evaluate the integral?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. For this case yes, but in the general case the exponent may be different to what the FT dictates.

Comment: Well, what would that exponent be then? The way you phrase the question means that your computing a Fourier transform, and there are very efficient ways to do that. If you want something else, it would be useful to state what "something else" is in your question.